# How would I cut off particular parts of a shape in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I want to get rid of the parts of the blue and red bars that are outside of the green circle, how can I cut these?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate the circle, and select the duplicate circle + one of the bars. *Path -> Intersection* will result in the bar cut to the circle.

Repeat for the other two bars.